# qTranslate-x - How to show just the flag on menu

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multilingual, qtranslate-x

I'm having problems with qTranslate-x because i need to show just the flag in the menu but it show with text and i don't know how to remove this.

Menu html:

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu( array(
     'menu'              => 'menu',
     'theme_location'    => 'primary',
     'depth'             => 2,
     'container'         => 'div',
     'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
     'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
     'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
     'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
     'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
?>
```

I just want the flag and i put this option on plugin settings.
[image]

Someone can help me? If doesn't work with this plugin, i can use another that do the same and can be used with acf plugin.

Thank you

Comment: You could customize the flag button with a snippet extending the feature from qTranslate.